# Micronaut testing - disable cache

Tags: groovy, spock, micronaut

Is there possible method to programmatically shut down caches? I tried inject DefaultCacheConfiguration in test class and set inside setup method set testMode=true and maximumSize=0, but still not working.

```
@MicronautTest
class CategoriesServiceTest extends Specification {

  @Inject
  @Shared
  DefaultCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration

  def setupSpec() {
      cacheConfiguration.setMaximumSize(0)
      cacheConfiguration.setTestMode(true)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found little hack. I'm not sure that is the best solution, but works.

I created class, which globaly shutdown caching for tests:

```
@Factory
class TestConfig {

    @EachBean(DefaultCacheConfiguration)
    CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration(DefaultCacheConfiguration configuration) {
        println "disabling cache ${configuration.cacheName}"
        configuration.maximumSize = 0
        return configuration
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting in 1.3.0.M1 a noop cache implementation was added that you can enable for tests or any other environment. See https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-cache/latest/guide/#noop

Comment: Beautiful...will be something same with scheduled jobs?